# How to access parent/sibling module methods

Tags: ruby

Is there any way to access `baz_method` inside `class Qux` without mentioning module namespace from first? When there are many nested modules the code doesn't look clean.

```
module Foo
  module Bar
    module Baz
      class Qux
        def self.qux_method
          Foo::Bar::Baz.baz_method  
        end
      end
      def self.baz_method
      end
    end 
  end
end
```

Comment: That's the whole purpose of namespace.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Constants are looked up first in the lexically enclosing module(s) and then up the inheritance chain.

```
module Foo
  module Bar
    module Baz
      class Qux
        def self.qux_method
          Baz.baz_method    
        end
      end
      def self.baz_method
      end
    end
  end
end
```

This will work, because the constant `Baz` will be first looked up in the lexically enclosing module (class) `Qux`, where it isn't found. The lookup continues in the lexically enclosing module `Baz`, where it also isn't found. Therefore, it will next be looked up in the lexically enclosing module `Bar`, where it *is* found and the search stops.

Note: you write in your title:

> Ruby, Access parent/sibling module methods

This is wrong. These modules are neither parents nor siblings. There is no inheritance here. There is, in fact, *no* relationship between the modules *at all*. There is *only* a relationship between the *constants* and the modules: constants belong to modules.

The module *declarations* are lexically nested, but the modules *themselves* aren't.

Answer (score 6):

You don't need to specify the entire namespace chain. You only need as much as is necessary to disambiguate the constant. Just use `Baz.baz_method`.

```
module Foo
  module Bar
    module Baz
      class Qux
        def self.qux_method
          Baz.baz_method
        end
      end

      def self.baz_method
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Duh. I can't believe I forgot about this writing my answer. +1.

Comment: I didn't know about `Module.nesting` though. It's not necessary here but it seems useful

Comment: It is, if you're doing something fancy.

Answer (score 2):

**Note**: Unless you're explicitly looking for relative module access, this metaprogramming is unnecessary. Use @drhining's [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34665270/1008938) instead.

You can dynamically climb the module hierarchy using `Module#nesting`:

```
module Foo
  module Bar
    module Baz
      class Qux
        def self.qux_method
          Module.nesting[1].baz_method  
        end
      end

      def self.baz_method
        puts "foo!"
      end
    end
  end
end
```

In this situation, `Module.nesting` will give the following (when called in `qux_method`): `[Foo::Bar::Baz::Qux, Foo::Bar::Baz, Foo::Bar, Foo]`

Note though that this is *not* an unambiguous reference to `Baz`, but rather to whatever happens to be one level up in the module chain.

Comment: `[Qux, Baz, Bar, Foo]` is not clear. Don't you mean `[Foo::Bar::Baz::Qux, Foo::Bar::Baz, Foo::Bar, Foo]`?

Comment: @sawa: I didn't mean it literally, but I guess I didn't make that clear. Changed it your version with full namespaces.

Comment: 'this is not an unambiguous reference to Baz': how can this be ambiguous? can you give an example?